# How to make a remote npm repository in Artifactory from format: git+https://url.git

Tags: git, npm, repository, artifactory

I'm using mdbootstrap pro which offers access to a gitlab repo. We can download tags (releases) there.

Now we can also use npm to install mdbootsrap pro:

```
npm install git+https://oauth2:TOKEN@git.url.com/mdb/angular/ng-pro.git --save
```

It's also described here: https://mdbootstrap.com/support/mbd-bootstrap-pro-npm/

But how can I mirror this repo in artifactory? So I can use:

```
npm install https://url/artifactory/my-remote-repo-to-mdbootstrap
```

We have a token, but we have also username/passwd to access the repo since I don't see a way in artifactory where I can provide that token.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create P2 Remote repo for this.